# LFS - Problems compiling point 5.8 Libstdc++7.3.0

Tags: compiling, gcc

I'm following the steps in LFS stable version, and got to point 5.8, passing the sanity test for the tool chain.
When trying to configure the lbstdc++, contained in the gcc-7.3.0 package, with the following commands:

```
../libstdc++-v3/configure           \
    --host=$LFS_TGT                 \
    --prefix=/tools                 \
    --disable-multilib              \
    --disable-nls                   \
    --disable-libstdcxx-threads     \
    --disable-libstdcxx-pch         \
    --with-gxx-include-dir=/tools/$LFS_TGT/include/c++/7.3.0
```

I get these warning messages:

```
configure: WARNING: stdbool.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: stdbool.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: stdbool.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: stdbool.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: stdbool.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for stdbool.h... no
checking stdalign.h usability... no
checking stdalign.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: stdalign.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: stdalign.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: stdalign.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: stdalign.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: stdalign.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for stdalign.h... no
checking for the value of EOF... configure: error: computing EOF failed
```

I checked if $LFS is correct, and it is.
When I opened the config.log, I saw this highlighted error message:

```
conftest.c:10:10: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
```

I imagine that these two are connected, but I don't know how to solve it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Linux From Scratch is not Ubuntu. Is not it?

Comment: It is not, but I saw other questions here about lfs and I am building it on ubuntu, so I thought it would be ok.